# syslog-ng and nginx logs to mysql

Tags: mysql, nginx, syslog-ng

So couple of days ago I asked
[how to log php and nginx logs to centralized MySQL database](https://serverfault.com/questions/447021/piping-nginx-and-php-fpm-logs-to-mysql), and m0ntassar gave a perfect answer :) cheer !

The problem I am facing now is that I can not seem to get it working.

syslog-ng version:

```
# syslog-ng --version
syslog-ng 3.2.5
```

This is my nginx log format:

```
log_format      main    '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
```

syslog-ng source:

```
source nginx { file( "/var/log/nginx/tg-test-3.access.log"
                     follow_freq(1)
                     flags(no-parse)
     );
};
```

syslog-ng destination:

```
destination d_sql {
sql(type(mysql)
host("127.0.0.1") username("syslog") password("superpasswd")
database("syslog")
table("nginx")
columns("remote_addr","remote_user","time_local","request","status","body_bytes_sent","http_    referer","http_user_agent","http_x_forwarded_for")
values("$REMOTE_ADDR", "$REMOTE_USER", "$TIME_LOCAL", "$REQUEST", "$STATUS","$BODY_BYTES_SENT", "$HTTP_REFERER", "$HTTP_USER_AGENT", "$HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"));
};
```

MySQL table for testing purposes:

```
CREATE TABLE `nginx` (
  `remote_addr` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remote_user` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `request` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body_bytes_sent` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `http_referer` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `http_user_agent` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `http_x_forwarded_for` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_local` text,
  `datetime` text,
  `host` text,
  `program` text,
  `pid` text,
  `message` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Now first thing that goes wrong is when I restart syslog-ng:

```
# /etc/init.d/syslog-ng restart
Stopping syslog-ng:                                        [  OK  ]
Starting syslog-ng: WARNING: You are using the default values for columns(), indexes() or values(), please specify these explicitly as the default will be dropped in the future;
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

I have tried creating a file destination and it all works fine, and then I have tried replacing my destination with:

```
destination d_sql {
sql(type(mysql)
host("127.0.0.1") username("syslog") password("kosmodromas")
database("syslog")
table("nginx")
columns("datetime", "host", "program", "pid", "message")
values("$R_DATE", "$HOST", "$PROGRAM", "$PID", "$MSGONLY")
indexes("datetime", "host", "program", "pid", "message"));
};
```

Which did work and it was writing stuff to mysql,

The problem is that I want to write stuff to in exact format as nginx log format is.

I assume that I am missing something really simple or I need to do some parsing between source and destination.

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: The broken link links to what was this page: http://web.archive.org/web/20130805073733/http://chaos.untouchable.net/index.php/HOWTO_setup_syslog-ng_to_log_to_mysql

Answer (score 4):

I can help you to write nginx access log to postgres. Lets go
**Nginx log format**

`log_format logtodb '$time_iso8601;$http_host;$remote_addr;$http_x_forwarded_for;$request_method;$request;$status;$body_bytes_sent;$http_referer;$request_time;$upstream_http_x_cache;$uri;$upstream_addr;$host;$upstream_response_length;$upstream_status;$server_name;$newurl;$upstream_response_time';`

`access_log /var/log/nginx/access_logtodb.log logtodb;`
Let's go.

**Configure syslog-ng**

```
nano /etc/syslog-ng/syslog.ng

#########################################################################
###### tailing nginx accesslog and sending to syslog-ng##################
source nginx_acceess_log { file( "/var/log/nginx/access_logtodb.log"
                    follow_freq(1)    
                    flags(no-parse)             
     );
};




parser p_nginx_acceess_log {
    csv-parser(columns("NGINX_TIME", "NGINX_http_host", "NGINX_remote_addr", "NGINX_http_x_forwarded_for", "NGINX_request", "NGINX_request_method","NGINX_status", "NGINX_body_bytes_sent", "NGINX_http_referer", "NGINX_request_time", "NGINX_upstream_http_x_cache", "NGINX_uri", "NGINX_upstream_addr", "NGINX_host", "NGINX_upstream_response_length", "NGINX_upstream_status", "NGINX_server_name", "NGINX_newurl", "NGINX_upstream_response_time")
         flags(escape-double-char,strip-whitespace)
         delimiters(";")
         quote-pairs('""[]')
         );
};



destination d_postgres_nginx_acceess_log{
  sql(type(pgsql)
  host("10.12.1.1")  port("5432") username("postgres") password("A1s2gdfgdfgdgdfgd")
  database("nginx_logs")
  table("access_log_nginx_223")
  columns("NGINX_TIME text", "NGINX_http_host text", "NGINX_remote_addr text", "NGINX_http_x_forwarded_for text", "NGINX_request_method text", "NGINX_request text", "NGINX_status varchar(3)",  "NGINX_body_bytes_sent text",  "NGINX_http_referer text", "NGINX_request_time text", "NGINX_upstream_http_x_cache text", "NGINX_uri text", "NGINX_upstream_addr text",  "NGINX_host  text", "NGINX_upstream_response_length text", "NGINX_upstream_status varchar(3)", "NGINX_server_name text", "NGINX_newurl text", "NGINX_upstream_response_time text")
  values("${NGINX_TIME}", "${NGINX_http_host}", "${NGINX_remote_addr}", "${NGINX_http_x_forwarded_for}", "${NGINX_request_method}", "${NGINX_request}", "${NGINX_status}", "${NGINX_body_bytes_sent}", "${NGINX_http_referer}", "${NGINX_request_time}", "${NGINX_upstream_http_x_cache}", "${NGINX_uri}", "${NGINX_upstream_addr}", "${NGINX_host }", "${NGINX_upstream_response_length}", "${NGINX_upstream_status}", "${NGINX_server_name}", "${NGINX_newurl}", "${NGINX_upstream_response_time}")
  indexes("NGINX_request", "NGINX_uri", "NGINX_server_name"));

};

log {source(nginx_acceess_log);  parser(p_nginx_acceess_log); destination(d_postgres_nginx_acceess_log); };
```

**Install packets for send to db**

```
apt-get install libdbd-pgsql -y
```

**Configure db-postgres**
Create database nginx_logs. Grant acceess in pg_hba.conf